# How to concatenate continuation lines in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl

I have a CSV file which contains strings like this:

```
ID1;banana
| apple
| oranges
```

and I want that every time there is a pipe at the beginning of the line, the string will be appended to the previous line, the output should be like this:

```
ID1;banana | apple | oranges
```

how can remove the newlines that precede a line begining with a pipe `|`?

Comment: Do you want to add a backspace, or remove the newline of the previous line?

Comment: A multi-line regex could take care of this, something like: `/\n\|/\|/m`.

Comment: Sometimes, when people have an unwanted control character, they say "I know, I'll insert a backspace". Now they have *two* unwanted control characters...

Answer (score 4):

In a hackish one liner, removing returns before pipes:

```
perl -ne '$s = do {local $/; <>}; $s =~ s/\n\|/ |/g; print $s' file.csv
```

Comment: most of that can be done with switches: `perl -0777 -wpe's/\n\|/ |/g' file.csv` (and the only thing that makes it "hackish" is you didn't enable warnings, which you should do even for one-liners.)

Comment: Aye, I haven't familiarized myself with `-0777` completely yet.  Would you happen to have a link to a resource that would discuss it?  Are there any pitfalls to its use? ty

Comment: Hello Miller, I tried your code but it says: > was unexpected at this time, how can I avoid this? Thank you.

Comment: I can deduce that means you're on a windows instead of unix box.  Use double quotes instead of single quotes around the expression.

Comment: yes, right, I'm using windows right now. Thank you very much!! It works fine :)

Comment: @ysth TY.  That's the one flag I shy away from because it's not easily deduced what it's doing by examining `perl --help`.  Thanks for at least reminding me where it is documented.

Comment: @ysth: There are those of us that consider Perl one-line commands to be inherently *hackish*.

Comment: @Borodin: then "hackish one liner" is redundant and the hackish still doesn't belong there :)

Comment: @ysth: Then *"the hackish still doesn't belong there"* is redundant and doesn't belong there :D

Comment: @Borodin: intentional joke

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to backspace/erase what's already been printed, you could instead only print the carriage return when a | isn't the first char:

```
perl -n -e 'chomp; /^\s*\|/? print " $_":  print "\n$_" ' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Clever approach.  The following is a little tighter: `perl -pe 'chomp; s/^(?!\|)/\n/ if $. > 1;' yourfile.txt`

Comment: Hello Magnus, when I tried your code I get this: '/?' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. What can I improve?

Comment: Sounds like you are on Windows perhaps?  Command line quoting rules might be different there... I only tested on OS X

Comment: Windows requires double quotes for command line parameters which means you'll probably want to use something like `qq( $_)` for interpolating strings...

Answer (score 0):

Is the string you show the value of a *single CSV field*? If so then you should be using `Text::CSV` to divide each line into fields (as its `getline` method is the simplest way to cope with data that contains embedded newlines) and you can use the substitution `s/\n(?=\|)/ /g` to change a newline into a space if it precedes a pipe character.

Here's an example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });

while (my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA)) {
  s/\n(?=\|)/ /g for @$row;
  print "$_: $row->[$_]\n" for 0 .. $#$row;
  print "\n";
}

__DATA__
"ID1;banana
| apple
| oranges",f2,f3
g1,g2,g3
```

**output**

```
0: ID1;banana | apple | oranges
1: f2
2: f3

0: g1
1: g2
2: g3
```

If your circumstance is different from that then you need to explain.